# Can I add a task to an asyncio loop that is already running a protocol server?

Tags: python-asyncio

Or, in other words, why does this code never print `Hello, world`:

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time

class EchoProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

loop = None
def serve():
    async def _serve():
        server = await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_server(EchoProtocol, '::1', 2000)
        await server.serve_forever()

    global loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(_serve())

async def hello():
    print("Hello, world", flush=True)

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=serve)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(hello)
    t.join()

main()
```

This sets up a TCP echo server on port 2000 which works as intended.  But the call to `call_soon_threadsafe()` doesn't seem to actually insert the new coroutine into the thread loop running in the thread.

Comment: Why are you using both `threading` and `asyncio`?

Comment: Because threads are pushed upon me here.  The code I've presented is a minimal reproducible example, not the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply that `call_soon_thread_safe`  takes a *regular* function, not an async function.

The function is called in the other thread as part of the scheduling of the asyncio loop, and, if needed it can call `asyncio.get_running_loop` and then iterate with it.

It is possible then to call `loop.create_task` to add new co-routines to be executed in the running loop - but not to do `asyncio.run` or `loop.run_until_complete`.

In other words, the task can be created in the synchronous function added as a callback from other thread, but you can't *await* for it - for few tasks, since the loop is running in the server, it will just work with "fire and forget":

```
async def hello_async():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("async hello")

def hello():
    print("Hello, world")
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(hello_async())
    return
```

(these two functions added in your listing will run both print statements: note that "hello" has changed from "async def" to just "def")

If you need a more elaborate thing, ensuring tasks from a foreign thread are executed and retrieving their results, it is best to have a permanent task checking a global structure where newly created tasks are added like:

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time

class EchoProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

loop = None
def serve():
    async def _serve():
        server = await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_server(EchoProtocol, '::1', 2000)
        await server.serve_forever()

    global loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(foreign_task_worker())
    loop.run_until_complete(_serve())


task_registry = []

async def foreign_task_worker():
    while True:
        if task_registry:
            # The quid-pro-quo with task_registry is so
            # to ensure new tasks are not ignored
            tasks = task_registry[:]
            task_registry[:] = []
            results = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            # do something with results
            ...
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def hello_async():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("async hello")

def hello():
    print("Hello, world", flush=True)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task_registry.append(loop.create_task(hello_async()))


def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=serve)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(hello)
    t.join()

main()
```

Note that asyncio won't *complain* if you do call `loop.create_task` passing a co-routine from the main thread - and it will even work *most of times* . However, the inner workings of the loop itself are not thread-safe, and eventually doing this will add a task in a point it will wreck the loop internal state.